# Is this exception caused by the dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't understand why I get this exception when I run the app.

I've create a dependency property in MainWindow class, and in ImagesGrid class I called on this property.

I did not make any changes in xaml. Should I have binded something there too?

This is code for dependency propoerty:

```
 public Visibility ButtonVisible
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ButtonVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonVisibleProperty, value); }
        }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonVisible", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

this is where I call on the property

```
  if (selectedModel is WineGroupModel)
        {
            MainWindow winesWindow = new MainWindow(); //mainwindow
            winesWindow.ButtonVisible = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            //some code
        }
```

THis is constructor MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        ImagesDir = @".\GalleryImages";

    }
```

This is xaml code for button:

```
<k:KinectCircleButton Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Foreground="#511C74"  Name="BacKinectCircleButton"  Label=""></k:KinectCircleButton>
```

This is the image:

http://i60.tinypic.com/5zqt5.png

Comment: take a look http://i59.tinypic.com/15qp53c.png

Comment: @user3137167, don't post as an image. Many enterprise proxies block sites like tinypic.com. Post the text of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a wrong default value for the property, as its type is `Visibility`, not `bool`.

Change the declaration to

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonVisibleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonVisible", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MainWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));
```

or leave out the property metadata completely:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonVisibleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonVisible", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MainWindow));
```

---

You would bind the `Visibility` property of the button to the property like this:

```
<k:KinectCircleButton ... Visibility="{Binding Path=ButtonVisible,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Comment: yes, the error is gone.. thankx, Clemeans. In order to hide the button, I should bind it somehow to this property I created, right?